# Portable generators - high THD (total harmonic distortion) ways to solve

Tags: electrical, generator

I was looking at portable generator options and it seems like very few have THD below 5%.  Is there a good (and reasonably priced) approach to cleaning up the power by using some sort of power conditioner or other device, or should I only consider ones which inherently produce clean power?

Comment: Kinda vague question, more is needed in the type of generator you are looking at. Old fashion alternator generators produce the cleanest power sine wave wise, but a little distortion for a more efficient unit can be a big deal to others.

Comment: WIth most electrical stuff using switching power supplies these days, I'm hard pressed to come up with something I own that really cares about the THD on input.

Comment: Everything depends on why exactly you need a nice clean sine wave. Can you add some details? Note that ordinary grid power in many places carries a lot of distortion as well.

Comment: Yeah, why do you need such finesse in your generator power?

Comment: @EdBeal Looking for a modern portable generator like that might be sold on Amazon or at Costco in the 7,000-12,500W range.

Comment: @TooTea From what I had read online is that some devices (appliances or electronics) will sense the sine wave is not clean and refuse to start, or some may start but be damaged

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Just replied to TooTea as to the rationale and to add some more clarity, the intent here is to have the generator power a house in an emergency via an inlet

Comment: G491 is gas ok alternator type? Not inverter. I think my service may have a higher total distortion but I can check with my power logger next week I am running a evaluation with it currently.

Comment: Do your homework and get a good generator. You should be fine. If it helps you sleep at night, use a UPS system for the stuff you're worried about.

Comment: @EdBeal Yeah I think alternator is good.  One I was looking at says "Alternator Type: Brushed" though it's a tri-fuel and I was thinking I'd run it on propane or natural gas.  I think I read that the inverter type actually has better THD, but I'm not sure if I recall that correctly.

Comment: @JACK I was also concerned about appliances / AC / TVs / etc., some of which would be harder to protect and was wondering if there's just a power conditioner or something which could be used to clean dirtier generator power before the inlet to avoid having to restrict the pool of generators to choose from way down or getting way pricey.

Comment: G491 a mid sized alternator style I have been running for 12+ years ~8.5 constant 13k surge, I have several large flat screens I have run while on generator digital box for both satellite and cable (different years). The only time I may have seen a glitch was when a bit overloaded & the well kicked in. Nothing is going to be perfect but true pure sine alternator will provide it, I did have a small Honda I bought for the computers but gave it to the kids years ago the specs sound good but when loaded it is electrically noisy compared to my alternator. Changing loads creates problems for both.